# how to overlay flot based plot onto an exisiting plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, flot

I have an existing plot using the flot javascript library, onto which, I would like to overlay another plot. What I mean is calling $.plot() twice, once with d1 data and again with d2 data is resulting in just plotting d2 data. Is there a way I could just overlay the second $.plot call onto the existing one?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Why can't you plot d1 and d2 together on the same plot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add another series to existing plot with flot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426648/add-another-series-to-existing-plot-with-flot)

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer. I had to do plot.getData() to get the existing series and then add my new series to it, call plot.setData() and then plot.draw()